# Inject Javascript into Chrome Extension window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to inject some javascript into an existing Chrome Extension's window (specifically Tab Outliner, a great extension).

I have created a Chrome extension that successfully injects a .js file into all windows and tabs (http:, https:, and probably file:) that are opened, but it does not seem to work in the Tab Outliner window (chrome-extension:).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, you can't inject JS into chrome-extension: pages

Comment: And it would be awful if it could be possible.

Comment: Shame - I just want to extend the extension.... add some more functionality. Does anyone else have an opinion (preferably one that lets me do what I want to do? :) )

Comment: Rewrite the original extension adding your wanted functionality? The original code is available once you install the extension...

Comment: You can do it locally by enabling `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls` - [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/19046796)

Comment: @wOxxOm, according to one of the links and a comment given there, 'chrome-extension is no longer a valid scheme'. So I guess that's a definite no. Thanks though, I didn't know that flag was there.

Comment: To be precise, it's an error that's displayed on browsers that don't have this flag enabled triggered on content script declaration using chrome scheme. You can still declare the scheme in `"permissions"` without this error and inject your code with `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.